# Dropzone and other html form inputs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to combine html form inputs and images through dropzone so that I can store them on my database. I tried using the fall back feature(without dropzone) everythig works fine; when I click the submit button with dropzone enabled, the text fields get saved to the database but the files (images) do not.

**the HTML**

```
<link href="css/dropzone.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <form   action="submit_vehicle.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" enter code heremethod="post">
        <input type="text" id ="Product" name ="Product" />
        <input type="text" id ="p_model" name ="p_model" />
        <div class="dropzone" id="myDropzone" name="mainFileUploader">
            <div class="fallback">
                <input name="files[]" type="file" multiple />
                <div class = "dropzone-preview"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit" id="submit-all" style= "display: none"> upload </button>
    </div>
        </form>
```

**the JS**

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
            url: 'submit_vehicle.php',
            paramName:'files',
            autoProcessQueue: false,
            uploadMultiple: false,
            parallelUploads: 100,
            maxFiles: 100,
            acceptedFiles: "image/*",

        init: function () {

            var submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit-all");
            var myDrop = this;

            submitButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
                myDrop.processQueue();
            });

            this.on("addedfile", function (files) {

                // Create the remove button
                var removeButton = Dropzone.createElement("<button class='btn btn-lg dark'>Remove File</button>");
                document.getElementById("submit-all").style.display = "block";
                // Listen to the click event
                removeButton.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                    // Make sure the button click doesn't submit the form:
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    // Remove the file preview.
                    myDrop.removeFile(files);

                });
            });

            this.on('sendingmultiple', function (data, xhr, formData) {
                formData.append("Product", $("#Product").val());
                formData.append("p_model", $("#p_model").val());
            });
        }
    };
```

**and finally the PHP**

```
$Product = $_POST['Product'];
$p_model = $_POST['p_model'];
$images=array();
$path = 'upload_test/';
$errors = array();
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    foreach ($_FILES['files[]']['tmp_name']as $key => $tmp_name) {
        $file_name = $key . $_FILES['files[]']['name'][$key];
        $file_tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];

     move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $path.$file_name);  
     $images[] = $file_name;


    }
    $imagestring =  base64_encode(serialize($images));
    $sql = "INSERT INTO test(Product, p_model, filename)VALUES('$Product', '$p_model','$imagestring')";
    $insert_details = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    if ($insert_details) {
        echo "success!!";
        echo base64_decode($imagestring)."<br>";
        print_r(array_values($images));//prints the values of an array 
        $keys = array_keys($images); 
        $imagename = $images[2]; //prints the second value of an array not good though
        echo "<img src = 'upload_test/Camera_20000102_075707.jpg' height = 50 width = 100>";
        //echo array_column($images,1);
        echo current($images);
        header('');
        exit();
        }else{  
        header('Location: vehicle.php');    
        }
    }
    else if(($Product)&&($p_model)){
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO test(Product, p_model)VALUES('$Product', '$p_model')";
                    $insert_details1 = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
                    if($insert_details1){echo "other info inserted but no files to add";
                    }
    }else{
        echo "empty form";
    }
```

Comment: Can you reduce this down to the minimum code required to reproduce the problem you're having?

Comment: Are you trying to send an image with text?

Comment: Like when a user needs to post a product, they input the product details in a form and attach photos with dropzone and when they click the submit button all the form contents are sent at once. The above code sends the details but not the photos. It seems to me like the dropzone code in someway fails to send the uploaded files to the php code.